# Regular Expression to restrict input field with atmost two decimal places

Tags: html, regex, input, decimal

Requirement:

I am trying to restrict the input field to key in only numbers or numbers upto two decimal numbers only. If the user enters more than two decimal places, the input field must display only number upto two decimal places and removing all other. I am using regular expression.

Problem:

When more than two decimal places are entered in input field, all the decimal places are removed and showed. Problem is with regular expression.

Kindly please help me with forming a correct regex.

Code:

http://jsfiddle.net/h6kYh/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#AmountField").bind("keyup change", function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

      var numericReg = /^d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/ ;
      if( !numericReg.test(value) )
      {
          value = value.replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g,"");
          $(this).val(value);
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
  var invalidNumericReg = /^\d+(\.\d{3,})$/;
  var validNumericReg = /^d+\(.\d{1,2})?$/;

  if( invalidNumericReg.test(value) )//has more than 3 decimal numbers!
  {
      value = value.replace(/^(\d+\.\d{2})\d+$/g,"$1");
      $(this).val(value);
  }
  else if( ! validNumericReg.test(value) )
  {
        //invalid input
  }
```

Comment: Replacement string should be `$1` not `\1`.

Comment: Thanks Anirudh. But i want to retain and display the numbers upto two decimal numbers, in case entered and remove only the decimals from third position. Can u plz suggest regex for it?

Comment: The input field accepts .655.5555, .65582722, .aahs.djdhdd, jj.d93.dijs.766 etc which is not expected.

Comment: @user2229399 check out the edit..you just have to check for invalid input

Comment: Yeah Okay Mike and Anirudh. I will try. Thanks a lot for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var numericReg = /^\d+\.?\d?\d?$/ ;
if( !numericReg.test(value) ) {
    value = value.replace(/^(\d+\.?\d?\d?)?.*/,'$1');
    $(this).val(value);
}
```

Comment: @user2229399. Fixed. I hadn't realised you were testing on every keyup.

Comment: `11.aa` would become `11.`

Comment: @Anirudh. Yes, if the OP is testing on every keyup, then a `.` without a digit after it must be allowed.

Comment: var numericReg = /^d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/ ;
      if( !numericReg.test(value) )
      {
          value = value.replace(/^(\d+\.?\d?\d?)?.*/g,'$1');
          $(this).val(value);
      }


Ok finally i arrived at this code. It accepts '12.' . But i want to change it to '12'. That is if a decimal dot is used without giving any decimal values, i want it to make it a whole number.